# Get : the improper use of a GetX has been detected

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, get, flutter-getx

Since I'm new to using Getx and while I'm trying to create  a drawer using Getx I'm facing this error. What did I do wrong? All I want is to get rid of this error.

Edit: the two methods invisibleSubMenu() and iconMenu() are showing the same error.

```
The following message was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state: _ObxState#b6fe5):
      [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
      You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
      If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into
GetX/Obx
      or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
      (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
      If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Obx
```

Here's the code.

Drawer class :

```
class DrawerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final bodyCtrl = Get.find<BodyController>();
  DrawerScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: row(),
    );
  }

  row() {
    return Row(
      children: [
        iconMenu(),
        invisibleSubMenu(),
      ],
    );
  }

  iconMenu() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[400],
      width: 100,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: drawerItemscdm.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Obx(
              () => InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  bodyCtrl.selectMenuIndex(index);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 45,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(
                    drawerItemscdm[index].icon,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  invisibleSubMenu() {
    return Container(
      width: 150,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Obx(
        () => ListView.builder(
            itemCount: drawerItemscdm.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Menucdm menu = drawerItemscdm[index];
              bodyCtrl.selected.value = bodyCtrl.selectedIndex.value == index;
              if (bodyCtrl.selected.value) {
                return subMenuWidget(menu.title, menu.submenu);
              }
              return invisibleWidget();
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container subMenuWidget(String title, List<Map> submenus) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
      height: 200,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: submenus.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                ...submenus.map((element) => ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(element['icon']),
                      title: Text(element['title']),
                    )),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  invisibleWidget() {
    return Container(
      height: 45,
      color: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```

The MenuCdm class :

```
class Menucdm {
  final IconData icon;
  final String title;
  final List<Map> submenu;

  Menucdm(this.icon, this.title, this.submenu);
}
```

The drawerItemscdm list:

```
List<Menucdm> drawerItemscdm = [
  Menucdm(FontAwesomeIcons.book, 'A', []),
  Menucdm(FontAwesomeIcons.book, 'B', [
    {
      'icon': FontAwesomeIcons.shop,
      'title': 'BA',
    },
    {
      'icon': FontAwesomeIcons.shop,
      'title': 'BB',
    },
    {
      'icon': FontAwesomeIcons.shop,
      'title': 'BC',
    },
    {
      'icon': FontAwesomeIcons.shop,
      'title': 'BD',
    }
  ]),
  Menucdm(FontAwesomeIcons.book, 'C', [
    {
      'icon': FontAwesomeIcons.gear,
      'title': 'CA',
    },
    {
      'icon': FontAwesomeIcons.gear,
      'title': 'CB',
    },
    {
      'icon': FontAwesomeIcons.gear,
      'title': 'CC',
    }
  ])]
```

The controller class :

```
class BodyController extends GetxController {
  final selectedIndex = (-1).obs;
  final selected = false.obs;

  void selectMenuIndex(int index) {
    selectedIndex.value = index;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using Obx where there is nothing to change with getx i.e
There must be .value written at the suffix of the variable data you are changing because obx will only look for .value

Drawer class :
in this class you are using obx but there is no value and you are just calling the getx controller function and passing index into that but not changing the value that's why it gives error

```
  iconMenu() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[400],
      width: 100,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: drawerItemscdm.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Obx(
              () => InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  return bodyCtrl.selectMenuIndex(index);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 45,
                  **alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(
                    drawerItemscdm[index].icon,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanx, i appreciate it,  and that solved the half of the problem, i'm still having the same error when it comes to invisibleSubMenu(), i'm using .value but nothing changed, any reason why?. thnx again

Comment: @HamouOuyaba 

what you are trying to do here??

  bodyCtrl.selected.value = bodyCtrl.selectedIndex.value == index;
              if (bodyCtrl.selected.value) {
                return subMenuWidget(menu.title, menu.submenu);
              }

at above bodyCtrl.selected.value you are giving it value as index and then you are calling it as bool

Comment: bodyCtrl.selected.value =  bodyCtrl.selectedIndex.value == index, here i'm comparing between the value of bodyCtrl.selectedIndex.value and the index using (==) the return will be bool

Comment: @HamouOuyaba
what bool value you are getting from this bodyCtrl.selected.value  ?

Comment: well the full code is too long to explain it here, i can assure you that  bodyCtrl.selected.value = bodyCtrl.selectedIndex.value == index it works perfectly if i don't use Getx.

Comment: if i delete Obx nothing will happen to the bodyCtrl.selectedIndex and the value will not going to change, same thing with the method bodyCtrl.selectMenuIndex(index). no idea whats wrong till now

Comment: @HamouOuyaba remove this line               bodyCtrl.selected.value = bodyCtrl.selectedIndex.value == index;

and then in if condition add this
if (bodyCtrl.selected.value==index)

Answer (score 0):

I have a conditional obx dependency like:

```dart
Widget buildView() {
  return (Obx(() => Column(children: [
    if (controller.argumentData.dict.isEmpty)
      Text(controller.state.value),
  ])));
}
```

Also face this error

My workaround is

```dart
Widget buildView() {
  return (Obx(() {
    0.obs.value;  // add line
    return Column(children: [
      if (controller.argumentData.dict.isEmpty)
        Text(controller.state.value),
    ]);
  }));
}
```